# EditTemplate of Pivot

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8, pivot, itemtemplate, pivotitem

I have a application page. In this page, I have 2 main control. They are Image and Pivot Control. I want to design the page same as:

[https://onedrive.live.com/redir?resid=C375ECE2AD56F56F%216996](https://onedrive.live.com/redir?resid=C375ECE2AD56F56F!6996)

In my page, the blue part covers Image (logo of app), the part one (white part) covers Pivot. The Header of Pivot is aligned indentation about 120px.

I don't know the way to make this page in WP.

Everyone help me, please!

Thanks very much.

Comment: Do you want logo static or movable when pivot item is changed? Or you want logo on each pivot item?

Comment: Yes, I want logo static. It same as this app:

http://www.windowsphone.com/en-us/store/app/money-lover/abf0e2c8-02e4-437a-be4b-35ce5f384b36

But the logo have Magin = (12,12,12,12) not (0,0,0,0).

Answer (score 0):

You can use the HeaderTemplate of the Pivot Control.

```
<phone:Pivot.HeaderTemplate>
    <DataTemplate>
        <Grid>
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding}" FontSize="{StaticResource PhoneFontSizeExtraLarge}"/>
        </Grid>
    </DataTemplate>
</phone:Pivot.HeaderTemplate>
```

Besides the Text, you will have to add your logo right next to it. You can use the Grid to place the image left to the text or use a stackpanel with horizontal content.

Update: forgot to mention the "phone" Namespace declared on top of the page:

```
<phone:PhoneApplicationPage
...
xmlns:phone="clr-namespace:Microsoft.Phone.Controls;assembly=Microsoft.Phone"
...>
```

Comment: I want the logo is static, same as:

http://www.windowsphone.com/en-us/store/app/money-lover/abf0e2c8-02e4-437a-be4b-35ce5f384b36

Comment: I don't understand, everything is static if you apply this.

Comment: My mind is The logo is not component of Pivot. The logo have margin Left is 12 and right is 12. And when we scroll the Pivot, header is not under the logo. Empathize for me because My English is very bad, I'm Vietnamese.

Comment: You should not scroll the pivot but only the pivot item content (e.g. LongListSelector). This way you will always see the pivot header and your icon. From a user experience the pivot shall always be visible.

Answer (score 0):

Hope, this may work for you. Modify it as per you requirement.

```
<Grid x:Name="ContentPanel" Grid.Row="1" Margin="12,0,12,0">
        <phone:Pivot>
            <phone:Pivot.HeaderTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <StackPanel Background="Blue"
                                Margin="15,-10,0,0">
                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding}"
                                   FontSize="20"
                                   />
                    </StackPanel>
                </DataTemplate>
            </phone:Pivot.HeaderTemplate>
            <phone:PivotItem Header="item1">
                <Grid Background="Red"></Grid>
            </phone:PivotItem>
            <phone:PivotItem Header="item2">
                <Grid Background="Green"></Grid>
            </phone:PivotItem>
        </phone:Pivot> 
        <Image Source="/Assets/abc.png"
               Height="30"
               Width="30"
               HorizontalAlignment="Left"
               VerticalAlignment="Top"/>
    </Grid>
```

Comment: Here is the result when I use the code.

https://onedrive.live.com/redir?resid=C375ECE2AD56F56F!7542&authkey=!APHbdfAMeJQV0yM&v=3&ithint=photo%2c.png

Comment: Hi, I saw the screenshot of your app. If you implemented above code in your application page then  set margin of header template StackPanel. Please mark this as answer if you found this helpful.

Comment: I think your answer is not helpful in my problem. Because I only want the header of Pivot is aligned indentation a space. It mean when we scroll the Pivot, the header of pivot is not under the logo.